# How to Validate an Email Duplicate Entry in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, validation

I need help to validate the email please teach me how.

Database Error After Inserting the Existing Email:
Image:

[image]

Creation Code For Adding a User

```
function student($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['mname']       = $this->input->post('mname');
        $data['lastname']    = $this->input->post('lastname');
        $data['birthday']    = $this->input->post('birthday');
        $data['sex']         = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['address']     = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']       = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['email']       = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']    = md5($this->input->post('password')); 
        $data['father_name'] = $this->input->post('father_name');
        $data['mother_name'] = $this->input->post('mother_name');
        $data['class_id']    = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $data['roll']        = $this->input->post('roll');
        $this->db->insert('student', $data);
        $student_id = mysql_insert_id();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/student_image/' . $student_id . '.jpg');
        $this->email_model->account_opening_email('student', $data['email']); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('add_student_success'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student/' . $data['class_id'], 'refresh');
    }
```

Comment: I would add the image to the post body, but its quality is awful. Can you post a better one?

Comment: sorry i need 10 reputation to post image im new here,

Comment: So you have codeigniter at your disposal, but you insist on using the ***deprecated, and unsafe*** `mysql_*` estension? I'm sorry, helping you to fix this code is like giving cyanide to somebody who is suicidal. I'm having no part in it. Oh: and don't spray tags: the JavaScript tag is not applicable to your question, so don't add it

Comment: You can't just use `mysql_insert_id()` when you have not even used mysql extension to that point. Try `$this->db->insert_id()`.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but it's safer to get the student ID by doing `$student_id = $this->db->insert('student', $data)->insert_id()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the form, add a validator for `is_unique`

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');
```

Comment: im sorry but i dont know where i put that code :(

Comment: @KarlGötze Are you using the form library?

Comment: i dont know what is form library in codeigniter?

Comment: @KarlGötze OK, look at the manual for [form validation library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html). It lets you add validators to each of the fields in your form.

Comment: so hard to make it. and it takes time :( and i dont know what to do . im so sorry

Comment: @KarlGötze What do you want it to do if it the email is not unique? Show a validation error?

Comment: yes, i want to show validation error like "Email is Already Exist" im so sorry i dont know how to do it. im new in codeigniter.

Comment: @KarlGötze it's kind of a long answer. If you don't want to use the `form_validation` library, then you'll need to do something like `if($this->db->get_where('student', ['email' => $email]) { \\ render original form with validation error };` You'll need to pass a 'student_validation_error' to the template, and render that. Honestly, though, learning the `form_validation` library would save you a whole lot of pain.

Comment: yah thats why it takes a lot of time to do it. and i need some help if anyone has a easiest suggestion to do the validation error, BTW Thanks for Helping me,, its a big help for me to learn.